# How to use jquery with jsdom in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jsdom

I want to use jQuery with jsdome in typescript.

Here is my code:

```
  import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
  import jQueryFactory from 'jquery';
  
  const jsdom = new JSDOM(html);
  const { window } = jsdom;
  (global as any).window = window;
  (global as any).document = window.document;

  const $ = jQueryFactory(jsdom.window, true); //does not work
  console.log($('.button').text());
```

Getting error  `Argument of type 'DOMWindow' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Window'.` in `jQueryFactory(jsdom.window, true);`

However the jQueryFactory signature is `jQueryFactory(window: Window, discriminator: boolean)`

I also tried that  `const $ = jQueryFactory(jsdom.DOMWindow.window, true);` but got another error `Property 'DOMWindow' does not exist on type 'JSDOM'. Did you mean 'window'?`

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed the problem using this `const $ = jQueryFactory(jsdom.window.parent, true);` but still wonder if this is the way...